# Spring Boot session won't invalidate

Tags: spring-boot, session

In my understanding the following Security configuration should forward to `/login` Page after the session is invalidated:

```
    ...
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/vendors/**", "/build/**", "/images/**", "/favicon.ico",     "/robots.txt").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/").successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
            .permitAll().and().sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).and().invalidSessionUrl("/login").and().logout().invalidateHttpSession(true);
    
    }
    ....
```

In my application.properties i add

```
    server.servlet.session.timeout=60s
```

But, it seems not being invalidated nor will the `/login` page be called. The webapp works still and no action due to sessionmanagement is performed. Where is my misunderstanding?